# How to assign value of the dataContext to ListBox control in silverlight?

Tags: silverlight

Hi I have contentControl in my user control. I am applying style to this contentControl which consist of TextBlock and ListBox. I am binding text of the textBlock to CategoryName(from Tag of the control). I want to bind category's child items to listBox. I have set ContentControl's dataContext property to child items[]. Now how to bind these child items to listbox which is in resource.

In loaded event of the user control
Panel pnl = sender as Panel;
Category category = panel.Tag as Category;
Items[] items = GetChildItemsByCategoryId(category.CategoryID);
mainContent.DataContext = items;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the control is in the visual tree of mainContent, simply set in code or XAML

ItemsSource={Binding}